# Multiple Math.pow in elasticsearch script_score not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an es query which uses script_score with multiple Math.pow nested into each other.
My formula is script = "_score + 4096*2^(-1/(x/64)^(1/2))"

```
"script_score": {
        "script": "_score + 4096/Math.pow(2,Math.pow(doc['count'].value/64, 0.5))"
```

But it is not working.

Comment: It works well. I tried `"script_score": {
            "script": {
                 "source": "_score + 4096/Math.pow(2,Math.pow((32/64), 0.5))"
            }
          }` and it returns `4096.2876` which appears correctly. Could you post your mapping and what value of `doc['count'].value` do you have. A sample document would help. I've tried in ES 7.

Comment: I want to update _score of a document. and add some value to it based on doc['count'].
After changing doc['count'] it does not change. always give me a constant value.